# p:menuitem onclick update not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsf, primefaces

I'm working on JSF/PrimeFaces but when i'm using a menuitem from the prime faces,that time my table panel not working automatically.

```html
<p:menuitem value="Hide Group" icon="ui-icon-close" styleClass="delete-group" onclick="pw_confirm_apply_end_date.show();return false" update="pnl_tbl_addr_group_mst" />

<p:confirmDialog widgetVar="pw_confirm_apply_end_date" message="Do you want to continue with applying end date?" style="width:300px">

  <p:commandButton id="btn_update_dlg" value="Apply End Date" icon="ui-icon-clock" process="@this" update=":form1:pnl_tbl_addr_group_mst,growl1" oncomplete="pw_confirm_apply_end_date.hide()" actionListener="#{addmst_grid.hideGroup}" />

  <p:commandButton value="Cancel" icon="ui-icon-close" onclick="pw_confirm_apply_end_date.hide();return false;" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```

When user clicked on Hide Group button that time it shows conform box and after they press apply then group can hide but panel updation not working.

```
public void hideGroup(ActionEvent event) {
    FcadAddrGrpMst ent_AddrGrpMst = fcadAddrGrpMstFacade.find(selectedGroupMst.getAgmUniqueSrno());
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    try {
        ent_AddrGrpMst.setEndDate(new Date());
        ent_AddrGrpMst.setUpdateby(new FhrdEmpmst(globalData.getUser_id()));
        fcadAddrGrpMstFacade.edit(ent_AddrGrpMst);

        try {
            setTbl_addr_group_mst();
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Hide Group", "Hide Group successfully"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logGenerator.generateLog(system_Properties.getSystemName(), Level.SEVERE, this.getClass().getName(), "hideGroup", null, e);
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Error in resetting components", "Hide Group successfully but error in resetting component(s) please refresh the page to view the changes"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logGenerator.generateLog(system_Properties.getSystemName(), Level.SEVERE, this.getClass().getName(), "hideGroup", null, e);
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error", "Some unexpected error occurred while saving record(s)"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there is any JavaScript error in your browser console ?

Answer (score 0):

onclick is handled in client side, but the update is done after an ajax event. In order to make the update working you need to do some ajax call, like the p:menuitem action or actionListener calling a server side method.

Comment: set the action to a method in your bean, and instead of onclick, set the onsuccess with the onclick value, and do not forget to set the update in the p:menuitem. I suggest to test it one by one, it is possible that the path you set in update is not right.